# How do I force Windows to forget the old mouse position after a SetCursorPos?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I'm trying to use SetCursorPos to move the cursor location when it hits the edge of the screen (for a scrubby control); the standard "track until the edge is hit, move cursor to middle of screen" thing.

The problem is that Windows resets the cursor location back to where it was as soon as it gets a mouse event.

For debugging purposes, I made a test app using the code at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Using_the_Keyboard_to_Move_the_Cursor

This is showing me the same behavior: I use the mouse to park the cursor in the top left corner of the window (right under the File menu) and use the keyboard to move the cursor off to wherever. But as soon as I touch the mouse, the cursor is right back to the top left corner.

This is obviously less than helpful for my control that uses the mouse to scrub.

How can I make Windows accept my SetCursorPos position as truth?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because the mouse driver (or some functionality that uses the mouse driver's information) tracks where the cursor is. Since the mouse driver itself just says "mouse moved x, y positions from it's current location", there is nothing else it can do but track the current position. I have a feeling there's nothing much you can do about that.

Comment: what you did seens to be correct, could you paste part of your code ?

Comment: Just follow the link to see code that does what I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Using SetCursorPos usually works fine (even though to use it is considered bad style in general.) Some devices such as a Wacom tablet send absolute positions, though. As soon as the device sends a new location, the cursor will jump back. You really can't help this if this is the case.

However, am I right assuming you're doing this because you're trying to detect the speed of the cursor? If so, you should probably use a different API that gives you the low-level values without the need to use the position of the cursor at all. Have a look at DirectInput!